# A FB Page or a Blog?

Tags: blog

Hi guys,

This is a slightly off topic question...i want to have a online presence to share my sound design/audio work...but im confused between having a blog(wordpress) where i can discuss my work and a FB page..

1. i want eveybody to see...not just FB users
2. link to wordpress blog to FB or vice versa
3. ability to link it to a profile website in future..
4. have my custom header image
5. easy update, insert vimeo / soundcloud links

so what do you suggest?

Also, if a blog, then self-host a blog or use wordpress hosted?

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with a blog.

Facebook is headed the way of myspace IMO.  They're constantly guilty of changing the rules midstream, and your entire presence will be subject to their whims.  [Also, the kids are moving from facebook to twitter.](http://www.debaird.net/blendededunet/2012/01/teens-leaving-facebook-for-twitter-heres-why.html)

With a blog you can control the entire presentation top to bottom, and change things on your terms.  You're in control of your own content, layout, and archives which is a huge deal.

Also, remember that the two are not mutually exclusive.  If you just do a facebook page then you just have a facebook page.  If you do a blog, then you can post updates to facebook and have both.

re:self hosting vs wordpress, IMO that depends on your vision for the blog.  Again, you're not locked into anything, so my advice would be to go with a wordpress host till you outgrow it, then move into self hosting.

of course, all of this is IMO, YMMV, etc.

Comment: For having tried both, I'd take a blog over a Facebook page anytime. However, I would create the FB page as well, and a twitter account to which my blog would post new entries. In fact I do have all of these but don't make use of it. Other people using this combo show quite a solid presence online, some of them hang around here sometimes...

Comment: @Rene and @Rig, I actually meant to +1 this post, got a little carried away :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd echo the previous comments...

I just launched a production blog/portfolio site hosted through wordpress.com (I'm not a developer, nor do I have time to learn the ropes of self-hosting).   It's extremely simple.  I then have all updates "publicize" through multiple online outlets - a dedicated Facebook page, LinkedIN, twitter, Google+, etc.   The FB, or G+ page can simply serve as another portal....nothing more than a simple bio, a few pictures, and links back to content on the main blog.